# function that replaces the negative numbers of an array with 77

Tags: matlab, indexing

```
function Z=replacez(A)
    [M,N]=size(A);
    for i=1:M
        for j=1:N
           if A(i,j)<0
              Z(i,j)=77;
           else
              Z(i,j)=A(i,j);
           end
      end
end
```

This is a simple function in MATLAB that replaces the negative numbers of an array `A` with the number 77.Can it be implemented without the `for` loops but with the `find` function instead?

So far I know the `find(A<0)` returns an array with the positions of the negative numbers of array `A`.For example `A=[1 , 0 , -3; -4 , 1 , -2]`,  `find(A<0)` will return `ans=[3 ,4 , 6]`

Comment: command such as A(A<0)=77 seems to do the trick but I cant seem to involve the find(x) function.

Comment: It's mandatory to use `find`? In that case, `A(find(A<0)) = 77`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If for some reason you really need to use `find`, I'll suggest your function to be

```
function Z = replacez(A)
  Z = A;
  Z(find(Z<0)) = 77;
end
```

But you should avoid it. Indeed, according to Matlab's [`find`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

> To directly find the elements in `X` that satisfy the condition `X<5`, use `X(X<5)`. **Avoid function calls like `X(find(X<5))`, which unnecessarily use find on a logical matrix.**

`find` is redundant here and you could do

```
function Z = replacez(A)
  Z = A;
  Z(Z<0) = 77;
end
```